Error: (0 , _lib_actions_user_action__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.getLoggedInUser) is not a function, even after the path is correct it shows error
I'm encountering an issue in my Next.js application where I'm trying to call an async function getLoggedInUser from user.action.ts, but I'm getting an error stating (0 , lib_actions_user_action__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_.getLoggedInUser) is not a function.
Code Snippets
layout.tsx
  import MobileNav from "@/components/MobileNav";
 import Sidebar from "@/components/sidebar";
 import { getLoggedInUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.action";
 import Image from "next/image";
 import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function RootLayout({
    children,
 }: Readonly<{
     children: React.ReactNode;
 }>) {
    const loggedIn = await getLoggedInUser();

    if (!loggedIn) redirect('/sign-in');

    return (
         <main className="flex h-screen w-full font-inter">
             <Sidebar user={loggedIn} />

             <div className="flex size-full flex-col">
                 <div className="root-layout">
                      <Image src="/icons/logo.svg" width={30} height={30} alt="logo" />
                       <div>
                        <MobileNav user={loggedIn} />
                      </div>
                  </div>
                {children}
             </div>
          </main>
    );
 }

user.action.ts

// Relevant imports and setup...
export async function getLoggedInUser() {
     try {
        const { account } = await createSessionClient();
        const result = await account.get();

         const user = await getUserInfo({ userId: result.$id });

        return parseStringify(user);
     } catch (error) {
         console.error("Error fetching logged-in user:", error);
        return null;
     }
   }

Steps Taken:
Verified import paths are correct (@/lib/actions/user.action).
Checked that getLoggedInUser is correctly exported from user.action.ts.
Expected Outcome
I expect getLoggedInUser() to return the logged-in user details when called in layout.tsx, but I'm encountering the (0 , lib_actions_user_action__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_.getLoggedInUser) is not a function error instead.
I even tried 'use client' in tayout.tsx but didnt help.
